# What will be the value of $\frac{1-x^x}{x \log x}$ as $x \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

We were taught L'hopital's rule and this is one of the questions from the assignment. I can't wrap my head around the indeterminate form that we get when we put in the limit.

Comment: Hello, my bad, I wasn't familiar with the approach that e^xlogx can actually be placed instead of x^x. We learn something new everyday, thanks a ton.

Comment: All four applications of L'Hopital in the four posts below are misguided since all assert that L'H is necessary to compute $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}t$$ when one knows beforehand the value of $$f'(0)$$ Which is **absurd**, to be explicit. Fortunately, one answer (not accepted, naturally) explains (rather implicitely, but still) the situation.

Comment: @Did: no one asserted that L'Hôpital is **necessary**. The OP seemed to be asking how to apply L'Hôpital. One could hijack the intent of the question and simply use the derivative, but the OP said the question was posed in the section on L'Hôpital. Most applications of L'Hôpital can be changed to applications of the derivative or mean value theorem. In my opinion, L'Hôpital is merely a convenience theorem.

Comment: @robjohn This is an age-old discussion and I am surprised by your approach to it. Simple logic indicates that when L'H is unnecessary or even absurd, it would be useful to at least mention in answers that it is so, and possibly to explain why. The evasion about "most applications etc.", is misleading as well: cases when using L'H may make sense are limits at $0$ of ratios $$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{g(x)-g(0)}$$ for relatively complex functions $f$ and $g$, but never of $$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x$$ For example, to invoke L'H to compute $$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{e^u-1}u$$ is, pedagogically speaking, a monstrosity.

Comment: @Did: another point of view is that if you have a tool, and it works, use it. Certainly, it may offend *your* sensibilities, but it is far from wrong to use it. Some people might want to carry one multi-tool, rather than a 2 screwdrivers, a file, scissors, and pliers. In the same way, when one sees a limit of the indeterminate form $0/0$, they may want to simply use L'Hôpital rather than, when $f(0)=0$, to have to recognize that, "hey, $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is essentially $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(0)$".

Comment: Instead of downvoting several **correct** answers, the person who downvoted could simply have given, what in their mind, was a superior answer.

Comment: @robjohn Sorry but your mathematical confusion on the topic seems to run deep (but rejoice, it is quite common): L'H is a tool which is built atop another, simpler, tool called derivative, and this higher level tool requires that some further hypotheses are met. To use the higher level tool (most of the time, without checking its hypotheses) to solve limits that are already written as ratios defining derivatives is illogical, mathematically speaking. (No "sensibility" involved here, only facts and logic, sorry.) Worse, anybody being on the site for some time ...

Comment: ...  can recognize the sorry situation of countless beginners desperately trying to fit every limit they meet in L'H's mold, even when this is absurd, as in the case of $$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{e^u-1}u$$ What would be a proper attitude when faced, as educators, with this? Imho, it should be to help them see the light rather than comforting them in their misguided views.

Comment: @robjohn "the person who downvoted could simply have given, what in their mind, was a superior answer" Hmmm... This bogus argument, already debunked countlessly many times, is disquieting under a mod's keyboard.

Comment: ((Note to myself: circularity.))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ x\log { x } =0 } $$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 1-{ x }^{ x } }{ x\log { x }  }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 1-{ e }^{ x\log { x }  } }{ x\log { x }  }  } \overset { L'Hospital }{ = } \ =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { -{ x }^{ x }\left( \log { x+1 }  \right)  }{ \left( \log { x+1 }  \right)  }  } =-\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { e }^{ x\log { x }  } } =-1$$

Comment: You should write it as $\frac {x}{\frac {1}{\ln (x)}} $ to get $0/0$.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima,thank you for mantion)

Answer (score 7):

> By equivalence.

$$1-x^x=1-e^{x\ln (x)}\sim -x\ln (x) $$
since $$\lim_{0^+}x\ln (x)=0$$
thus your limit is $-1$.

> By usual limit.

Put $t=x\ln (x) $.

as $x\to 0^+ \;\; , t \to 0$.

the limit is
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac {-(e^t-1)}{t}=-1$$

> By l'Hospital.

Put $f (x)=x\ln (x) $.

$$\lim_{0^+}\frac {1-e^{f (x)}}{f (x)}=$$
$$\lim_{0^+}\frac {-f'(x)e^{f (x)}}{f'(x)}=$$
$$\lim_{0^+}(- e^{f (x)})=-e^0=-1$$

Comment: Hi, I don't think I get the solution. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: (+1) My answer seems similar, but more concise. If you think it is too close, I will delete mine.

Comment: @robjohn No, if you want delete mine. No problem friend. thnx.

Comment: In your first approach, $f(x)\sim g(x)$ near $x=0$ means $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$, so you are saying that $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{1-x^x}{x\log(x)}=-1$ because $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{1-x^x}{-x\log(x)}=1$. Your other approaches are fine, however (as I said, I've already upvoted).

Comment: @robjohn You are a good man . i love people like you. :).

Answer (score 3):

Since $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}x\log(x)=0$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1-x^x}{x\log(x)}
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1-e^{x\log(x)}}{x\log(x)}\\
&=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{1-e^u}{u}\\
&=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{-e^u}{1}\\[6pt]
&=-1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Three answers to this question were downvoted this morning. Is it the use of L'Hôpital? If so, why is that a problem? If not, what is wrong with the answers downvoted?